# ListFields in Feature Classes in Multiple Feature Datasets in Oracle SDE

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, enterprise-geodatabase, for-loop

I need to create individual reports for feature classes that contain the field "FACILITY_STATE" AND "FACILITY_STATE = 'PPC'". These feature classes span multiple feature datasets within an Oracle SDE.

I am looping through datasets within the SDE connection, then looping through feature classes, and if the feature class contains the field "FACILITY_STATE", using a search cursor, I append each row to a list of rows WHERE "FACILITY_STATE ='PPC'". Write this list to a csv named by feature class. I am fairly new to python and VERY new to working within SDE so I am not sure if I am losing connection or if I am not setting the loops up correctly, but my script runs the way it should until reaching a specific dataset. After that point, my script tells me that each feature class does not contain the FACILITY_STATE field, but I am positive that a good number of them do. What could be going wrong?

```
# Import modules
import arcpy
import os
import csv

# Roaming SDE environments and variables
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
sde_conn_file = r'C:\Users\caree\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.6\ArcCatalog\gepr.sde'
facilityState = 'FACILITY_STATE'
inclFields = ['OID@', 'FACILITY_STATE', 'DATE_PLACED', 'PLACED_BY', 'DATE_MODIFIED', 'MODIFIED_BY']
arcpy.env.workspace = sde_conn_file

# Proposed construction report
for ds in arcpy.ListDatasets():
    dspath = sde_conn_file + os.sep + ds
    print('Listing feature classes in: {}'.format(dspath))
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('', '', ds):
        flist = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
        if facilityState in flist:
            print('Running PPC report for {}...'.format(fc))
            fcRows = []
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, inclFields, "FACILITY_STATE = 'PPC'") as cursor:
                for row in cursor:
                    fcRows.append(row)
                    with open(r'C:\giswork\ppcReport\{0}.csv.'.format(fc), 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                        writer.writerow(inclFields)
                        writer.writerows(fcRows)
            print('PPC report created for {}'.format(fc))
        else:
            print('{0} not in {1}'.format(facilityState, fc))
```

Comment: Putting dev code in a huge `try` block can actually hurt debugging. Re-applying the same workspace for each fds could increase runtime.

Comment: @Vince thanks, I have removed the try block and cleaned up my code a bit in the original post. I switched my sde connection to simply use the connection path stored on my local ArcCatalog. Everything runs, but I am not getting any fields in my flist   after the same dataset. Could it be something to do with the actual feature class and how its stored on sde?

Comment: Are all your feature classes in feature datasets? If not, then this code won't ever query them. You might be better off just not listing fds, any not nesting the fc-within-fds queries.

Comment: @Vince yes every feature class is stored in a feature dataset.

Comment: Could you print what's in the `fc` variable? Because I suspect that's just the short name of the featureclass, whereas you would probably need the full name, e.g. `path_to_sde\featuredataset\featureclass`

Comment: Also, I *think* the first two parameters of ListFeatureClasses should be `None` rather than `''`. Not 100% sure, though

Comment: @Berend regarding the fc, I am going to give that a try, I had actually had this thought previously, but I do get results for the first two datasets, after that I just get empty 'flist'